# Get all diagnostics for the open file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Just wondering if its possible to get all the diagnostics for the current file? Im looking to implement a 'Fix all' command for my extension.

Currently I am using the CodeActions provider by that only provides a diagnostic for the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not see any way to do this from the API.

The only API's I see are for creating your own diagnostics.

Are the diagnostics that you need to fix created by you? If so, you might take inspiration from the [tslint extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/blob/36bb470b475a728184af69a15227b5391b78c9fc/tslint-server/src/server.ts)

Basically, whenever you validate a file an create your diagnostics, check each to see if it is a "fixable" problem, create the edit that is needed to fix it and push it to a collection. You can register a "fixAll" command which will then go through and fix everything.